# text turned into strange Chinese characters when trying to write to file C++

Tags: c++, csv, file, getline

When I compile my code all is good no errors but when I open the file that I am writing too I see that most of the text has been converted into strange Chinese looking characters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;


 int main()
 {
    string temp, line;

    fstream file("LogData.csv");
    fstream txtfile("temp.txt", ofstream::out, ofstream::trunc);

    while (getline(file, line, '\n'))
    {
        txtfile << line;
    }

    file.close();
    txtfile.close();
}
```

Comment: Open the file in a hex editor to see what's inside. Could be an incorrect BOM.

Comment: what do you mean by that its just a blank txt file? i used cout << line; to see if the characters were messed up before it was written to the file and it was all normal

Comment: In the question, you say it is filled with Chinese characters, but in the comment you say it's a blank file. Which one is it?

Comment: `cout << line` isn't necessarily going to tell you anything if the underlying characters have a different encoding, because your terminal might automatically translate the output (_e.g._ UTF8).  Hence the suggestion to open the CSV file in a hex editor.  It might be using a different encoding to what you expect.  The presence of a BOM will further help determine that the file is not ASCII.

Comment: What editor are you looking at it in? Windows Notepad is notorious for guessing the wrong format of text.

Comment: @RaymondChen the file is empty when the program starts but once it finishes i go and look at what i wrote to it and its filled with Chinese characters

Comment: @RetiredNinja i am using Notepad

Comment: @paddy im not to good with a hex editor but im pretty sure its in UTF8

Comment: Is there a BOM at the start of either file?

Comment: @RaymondChen How would i find that out? I'm assuming i put it in a hex editor but I'm not sure what a BOM would look like. at the beginning of my csv file there is a symbol that looks like this ÿþ and the hex values for it are FF FE, not sure if this is anything.

Comment: That's the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding).  The value indicates the characters are UTF-16 stored as little endian.  You must read the data accordingly.

Comment: That also means that the original CSV data is also in Chinese. (Two ASCII characters combined into a UTF-16 code unit produces a Chinese character.) So your copy was accurate.